# Angular | Load Content by ID

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a sub navigation in my app (/items):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button md-button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/item-detail/', item.id]">
        <div class="first">
            <md-icon>live_help</md-icon>
                   <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        </div>
         </a>
    </button>
</ng-container>
```

It works by loading items I have in an array:

```
 items = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Item 1',
        textContent: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus enim purus, ac posuere nibh facilisis sit amet. Nam congue venenatis dictum. Donec non dui porttitor, rutrum lectus at, pharetra ante. Nulla facilisi. Quisque lectus sapien, finibus eget ullamcorper nec, iaculis ac risus. Sed in enim eget tellus mattis interdum ac eu urna. Ut erat ante, efficitur vitae egestas vel, fringilla iaculis enim. Vivamus laoreet est ex, in rutrum ipsum pellentesque faucibus.'
      }
    ];
```

By clicking on the button the app routes to **/items/item-detail/1** (would work as well if I had more objects in my array

In my routing I defined a detail component for the route mentioned above:

```
 path: ':id',
                component: ItemDetailComponent,
                data:
                {
                   title: 'Item Detail',
                }
```

The routing seems to work but whenever I try to show attributes in my HTML I don't get the desired content that's in the object.

```
  <div class="text">
        <h2>Text Content</h2>
        <p>
                {{item.textContent}}
        </p>
    </div>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Because you only provide the item id in your route :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/item-detail/', item.id]">
```

You need to use a service to share your items between your components, or make an HTTP call in your second component (that's usually what routign is for).

Comment: But I already provide the array in my detail component, so the data to display is already there

Comment: It is there **in your component**, but it isn't **in the other component**.